# Shredding XML data in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008, xquery-sql

I need to import the following XML into SQL Server 2008 R2:

```
<Role
  ID="ef63f979-c65d-421a-a214-7319c6279e13" >
  <Privileges>
    <Privilege ID="1" />
    <Privilege ID="2" />
    <Privilege ID="3" />
    <Privilege ID="4" />
    <Privilege ID="5" />
  </Privileges>
</Role>
```

I am able to do this using a table variable and parsing the XML twice, but am unable to get this into a relational table in one parse. Is that possible? Here is the expected result set:

```
EF63F979-C65D-421A-A214-7319C6279E13    1   2011-12-05 06:51:11.9065096 EF63F979-C65D-421A-A214-7319C6279E13
EF63F979-C65D-421A-A214-7319C6279E13    2   2011-12-05 06:51:11.9065096 EF63F979-C65D-421A-A214-7319C6279E13
EF63F979-C65D-421A-A214-7319C6279E13    3   2011-12-05 06:51:11.9065096 EF63F979-C65D-421A-A214-7319C6279E13
EF63F979-C65D-421A-A214-7319C6279E13    4   2011-12-05 06:51:11.9065096 EF63F979-C65D-421A-A214-7319C6279E13
EF63F979-C65D-421A-A214-7319C6279E13    5   2011-12-05 06:51:11.9065096 EF63F979-C65D-421A-A214-7319C6279E13
```

Thanks,

Raj

Comment: You mean without programming? Because this would bea beginner exercise in programming.

Comment: The requirement is to write a stored proc that will do this and I need the SP to perform efficiently

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can extract this :

```
DECLARE @input XML = '<Role
  ID="ef63f979-c65d-421a-a214-7319c6279e13" >
  <Privileges>
    <Privilege ID="1" />
    <Privilege ID="2" />
    <Privilege ID="3" />
    <Privilege ID="4" />
    <Privilege ID="5" />
  </Privileges>
</Role>'

SELECT
    @input.value('(/Role/@ID)[1]', 'uniqueidentifier') AS 'ID',
    T.C.value('(@ID)[1]', 'int') AS 'Privilege'
FROM
    @input.nodes('/Role/Privileges/Privilege') AS T(C)
```

Gives output:

```
ID                                     Privilege
EF63F979-C65D-421A-A214-7319C6279E13    1
EF63F979-C65D-421A-A214-7319C6279E13    2
EF63F979-C65D-421A-A214-7319C6279E13    3
EF63F979-C65D-421A-A214-7319C6279E13    4
EF63F979-C65D-421A-A214-7319C6279E13    5
```

but I have no clue where your date/time comes from.....

Comment: Likely the insertion timestamp?